# OpenCL broken on 11.10, CUDA works

Tags: nvidia, cuda, opencl

I have two GPUs, one is AMD (fglrx-updates) and one nVidia (nvidia-current), drivers from x-swat PPA. The AMD card is used byt xorg (without problems). Both devices show up in `lspci|grep VGA`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Device 6718
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 1200 (rev a1)
```

The nvidia kernel module is loaded (`dmesg|grep nvidia`):

```
[   16.033488] nvidia 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   16.033501] nvidia 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 40 (level, low) -> IRQ 40
[   16.033507] nvidia 0000:02:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
```

**OpenCL problem**

I created `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd` containing

```
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so
```

The device is detected, platform `NVIDIA CUDA`, device `GeForce GTX 560 Ti`. However, no code gets compiled for the device, `clBuildProgram` always returns `CL_BUILD_RPOGRAM_FAILURE` and querying `clGetProgramBuildInfo` crashes with uninformative backtrace

```
#0  0x00007ffff7442bef in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff22c0e67 in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so
```

The program is build with `cl.h` from Intel's SDK; that is OK since everything was fine until I installed the AMD card alongside.

Running `/usr/share/doc/python-pyopencl/examples/benchmark.py` crashes just the same (in `pyopencl::program::get_build_info`).

Any hint on what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation probably can't dlopen one of the libraries it uses, try running your app with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./yourapp`, and if that doesn't help run it with strace, and look out for libraries it's unable to load and adjust the path so it can find them.

Comment: It segfaults in `libcuda.so` (calling `strlen` from glibc); `libcuda.so` is found just fine, it is given (including path, which avoids the need for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) in the ICD file in `/etc/OpenCL/vendors`.